# How to upgrade old Objective C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, ios11

I have an old Objective C project with iOS 7 deployment target and xCode 3.2 compatible version. And now I need to continue working on it. When I’m running the app on iOS 12 device the StatusBar and Keyboard are old styled and there are empty black spaces on `iPhone X*`’s top and bottom edges of the screen.

How can I upgrade the iOS sdk version? Is there any way to make it look like a new iOS?

I changed the deployment target and xCode compatible version (I’m using xCode 10.2.1) also accepted XCode’s `Update to recommended settings`

Comment: As for the keyboard, you’d need to provide launch screen images for new resolutions. And as for the top/bottom spacing you will most likely need to update your constraints to account for the notch.

Comment: Thanks @Losiowaty! . removing LaunchScreen images and adding LaunchScreen.xib as a Launch Screen file solved the issue